# How to get gtest results?

Tags: c++11, googletest

How to get the result of EXPECT_EXIT() in gtest?

I want to do something according to the results of EXPECT_EXIT. For example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    auto &result = EXPECT_EXIT(Function(i, inputs[j]));
    if (result) {
      do something;
      break; //jump out of the loop
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What kind of result do you expect? It's an odd way of testing. Please explain why you need this in order to avoid an X/Y problem.

Comment: Index i: there are about 1000 Functions to be tested.  Index j: and for each function, there are different inputs to be tested(Asuming 1000 test case for each Function). So I test the 1000 Functions one by one and provide it with different inputs. But once it failed, I need record something and skip rest of the input check for this function.

Comment: I reduced the input parameters from 1000 to 10 to make it much more reasonable.

Comment: It's an odd way of testing to stop at all. Normally you'd have a value-parameterised test

Answer (score 1):

From your comment:

> But once it failed, I need record something and skip rest of the input
> check for this function

### Short answer:

To stop execution at first mismatch you need to use `ASSERT` version instead of `EXPECT`, in your case `ASSERT_EXIT`.
To output some extra data for failed check you can just use stream operator of check:

```
ASSERT_EXIT(Function(i, j), testing::ExitedWithCode(0), "") << "Some custom data: " << i << "; " << j;
```

If you want to do something more on fail - you can use [::testing::Test::HasFailure()](http://google.github.io/googletest/reference/testing.html#Test::HasFailure) function.

### Long suggestion:

One of the properties of good unittest is simplicity. That implies absence of any loops or branches. Setup logic (if any) should be moved to fixtures. Also unittests must be executed in isolation.

By switching your test to parametric one you would cover that. Check this:

```
void Function(int i, int j)
{
    if (j != 3)
        exit(0);
}

class FunTest : public testing::TestWithParam<std::tuple<int, int>> { };

TEST_P(FunTest, Should_Exit)
{
    const auto i = std::get<0>(GetParam());
    const auto j = std::get<1>(GetParam());

    EXPECT_EXIT(Function(i, j), testing::ExitedWithCode(0), "");
}

INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P(,
    FunTest,
    testing::Combine(
        testing::Range(1, 20),
        testing::Range(1, 10)),
    [](const testing::TestParamInfo<std::tuple<int, int>>& info) -> std::string {
        const auto i = std::get<0>(info.param);
        const auto j = std::get<1>(info.param);
        return std::to_string(i) + '_' + std::to_string(j);
    });
```

This approach would help with your problem: you can stop execution by using `--gtest_break_on_failure` and you can control naming of test cases by implementing custom printer for specific `TestParamInfo` (lambda in example).

It would also guarantee isolation and provide certain level of simplicity (all complex stuff provided by framework, imho test code is minimalistic and simple).

Also this would allow execution of specific test using gtest_filter
(e.g. `--gtest_filter=FunTest.Should_Exit/4_3`).